# OAuth2 function vs 2FA?

Tags: oauth

Please correct or comment where needed as I'm confused even after reading material on OAuth2. (wasn't sure where to post, please move if necessary with notice, thanks)

If I understand what I've read correctly (?) OAuth2 is for "Server Site Authorization" of certain parameter(s) access (designated by Server site) given to a requesting entity (or App).

Whereas 2FA is about Authenticating an Account Owner entity logging into an Account on the Server Site (with full owner access). This via phone SMS or better with an App like Google Authenticator or Authy.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading more and it appears these are part of the same whole but not the same functions depending on application. I.e. say a person sets up an IMAP email account up for 2 Factor Verification as it's called in some accts (others say 2FA). Then if they log into said acct via a web browser, after giving their password, they will be sent a code either SMS to a Phone (or better to an Authenticator App on Phone or PC). 
But if after they've set up aforesaid email acct with 2FA, they decide to use an Email client app to access the email. And if the email client supports OAuth2, then in client app acct setup in the Authentication drop down will also be the choice of OAuth2 listed.

Now I've never done this but I plan to soon. And I surmise by doing this the email client app will then be given an App Specific Password that will then be put into the client app's acct setup for that acct. I surmise from then on it will log in the same way it did prior under less secure password access. I further surmise the reason this "App Password" given through OAuth2 is more secure than prior Password usage is because of certain limited access parameters set by the server though the OAuth2 paradigm. (Yes, No, comment ?)